# Call to undefined relationship [person] on model [App\Note]

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a notes, cards and person table where the notes table has card_id and person_id.

Once I load card data I also want to load person name's name but Laravel give this error:

> Call to undefined relationship [person] on model [App\Note].

sorry my English is not good.

These are my relationships:

notes:

```
public function card()
   {
       return $this->blongsTo(Card::class);
   }

public function person()
  {
      return $this->blongsTo(Person::class);
  }
```

cards:

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

persons:

```
public function notes()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Note::class);
}
```

and this my action:

```
        public function showCard(Card $card)
        {
    
           $card->load('notes.person');

           return view('cards.card',compact('card'));
        }
```

what's wrong?

Comment: try: `$card->load('notes.user');`

Comment: yeah my bad ... i edite my question ... but the notes with user table also give me same error ... then i gust maybe issuse is beacuse of my table and change to person

Answer (score 1):

You have a spelling mistake. Check the relationship, it says: ->blongsTo instead of belongsTo.

```
public function card()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Card::class);
}

public function person()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Person::class);
}
```

Comment: thanks man :)))) i dont know why my english is so bad :))) you'r save my day